# Chinese Dictionary Question

Tags: mandarin, dictionary

What do the characters in angle brackets signify?

Examples:

[image]

http://www.zdic.net/z/15/xs/4E48.htm
"〈后缀〉"   "〈助〉"

http://www.zdic.net/z/16/xs/54C1.htm
"〈形〉"   "〈名〉"   "〈动〉"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- 后缀 = suffix
- 助动词 = auxiliary verb
- 形容词 = adjective
- 名词 = noun
- 动词 = verb

Comment: Thanks. So 助, 形, 名, 动, are abbreviated forms of 助动词, 形容词, 名词, 助动词. Is there a reference that lists all parts of speech and their corresponding abbreviated form?

Answer (score 0):

Every good dictionary has the definitions of the words and its classes. The class of the word comes before the definition of thereof. That way you might know what is its definition as used in a specific class before you even read its definition. By classes I mean: nouns, verbs, pronouns, suffixs, etc. For exemple, the word 么 as a suffix has a different meaning when compared when used as a "auxiliary"

Comment: Please also answer the original poster's specific question.

Comment: Is just that I think the question is "what do the characteres in angle brackets mean in general". Not what they mean specifically in this case. That's why I've only answered that they're put there to distinguish the class of the word (or classes depending on the word).